# NOOB: Parse API data and output one item

Tags: php, jquery, citymapper-api

apologies for how simple this question is.

I have this link from the Citymapper API:

```
https://developer.citymapper.com/api/1/traveltime/?startcoord=51.513895%2C+0.021222&endcoord=51.524006%2C+-0.115490&key=8b3e89fd32441463296274661805caba
```

when I point the browser there it gives me:

> {"travel_time_minutes": 51, "diagnostic": {"milliseconds": 3036}}

I am  trying to pull out one item from it; the "51".

I would then want to display it on an html webpage to say: "51 minutes to work"

I know this is very simple, but I just can't work out any of the documentation on how to deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery `$.ajax` function for this.

```js
var url = 'https://developer.citymapper.com/api/1/traveltime/?startcoord=51.513895%2C+0.021222&endcoord=51.524006%2C+-0.115490&key=8b3e89fd32441463296274661805caba';


$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: url,
  dataType: 'jsonp',    
  crossDomain: true,
  success: function(data){
    $('.data').html(data.travel_time_minutes + ' minutes to work');
  }        
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="data"></div>
```

Comment: thanks. How would I use the actual link (which is constantly refreshing) instead of just the data from it? do I need to use some form of GET like Benjamin's response?

Comment: @rwattstci, I've updated my post. This way You can get necessary data from actual link.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**JavaScript:**

```
$.get('https://developer.citymapper.com/api/1/traveltime/?startcoord=51.513895%2C+0.021222&endcoord=51.524006%2C+-0.115490&key=8b3e89fd32441463296274661805caba').done(function(data) {
    $('#ElementToDisplayIn').html(data.travel_time_minutes+' minutes to work.');
});
```

Since you've tagged the question with jQuery, I'm using [jQuery's $.get method](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/). The API you're using is spitting back JSON, which jQuery automatically transforms into a JavaScript object for you.

When the request is successful, I'm setting the html of a element with the id `ElementToDisplayIn` to the string you requested.  The variable `data` is what's being returned from the API and has all the information in it from there.

For example, to access the milliseconds I can do `data.diagnostic.milliseconds` which will spit back `3036` in your example.

Hopefully that will get you started!

Comment: Thanks. I only mentioned jquery as that seemed to be what the internet was suggesting to use. I think I am doing something wrong. As an example if I do something like: `<html>
<body>
<script>
$.get('https://developer.citymapper.com/api/1/traveltime/?startcoord=51.513895%2C+0.021222&endcoord=51.524006%2C+-0.115490&key=8b3e89fd32441463296274661805caba').done(function(data) {
    $('#ElementToDisplayIn').html(data.travel_time_minutes+' minutes to work.');
});

</script>


</body>
</html>` then I just get a blank page